# recreation on grid banner not aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve similar effect like in this topbanner: http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo

However when i create it the images seem to not align proberly. How can i make sure that they always align properly like in the link above?

You will properly need to adjust your browser since below 767 it will readjust due to responsive design.

```css
@import url('http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/simpleGrid.css');

.column-big {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
 .column-small-1 {

  width: 100%;
 
  padding-bottom: 10px;

}
.column-small-2 {
    padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  

}

   .column-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.column-content .meta-info-doub {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}
.column-content .meta-info-norm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.title-double {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  background: #161616;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title-normal {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  background: #161616;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.date-double {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}
.date-normal {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}
.column-content .content-image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.column-content .content-image:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-pad">
   <div class="col-8-12">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="column-content">
            <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
            <div class="meta-info-doub">
              <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
              <h3 class="title-double">Post2</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4-12">
    <div class="content">
     
    <div class="column-small-1">
      <div class="column-content">
        <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
        <div class="meta-info-norm">
          <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
          <div class="info-title">
            <h3 class="title-normal">Post 3</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-small-2">
      <div class="column-content">
        <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
        <div class="meta-info-norm">
          <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
          <div class="info-title">
            <h3 class="title-normal">Post1</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's the issue here, but if you remove padding-top (or set it to zero) from right hand side bottom image, you'll get bottom image on right hand side aligned to the baseline of big banner on the left.

```
.column-small-2 {
   padding-top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT:

I know what your main problem is. Your big banner image doesn't stretch to its full height. This is happening because you're using `width:100%` on `.column-content .content-image` class. This makes the image being displayed as 727px X 351px, as brwoser retains original ratio of the image.
Now because total height of your left hand side bar is 360px, you're getting this disjointed, misaligned layout.
To resolve this, you need first to provide a main image of 360px height, and then to change the rule `width:100%` on `.column-content .content-image`class to `max-width:100%;`. Then because this rule applies also to your right hand side I'll call them thumbs, you need to restore your old `width:100%` rule on them. So add a class ie `content-image thumb` and style it `width:100%`.
This makes things align as per example of the site you provided.
Let me know if this is unclear.
Cheers

```css
@import url('http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/simpleGrid.css');

.column-big {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
 .column-small-1 {

  width: 100%;
 
  padding-bottom: 10px;

}
.column-small-2 {
    padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  

}

   .column-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.column-content .meta-info-doub {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}
.column-content .meta-info-norm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.title-double {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  background: #161616;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title-normal {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  background: #161616;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.date-double {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}
.date-normal {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}
.column-content .content-image {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.column-content .content-image:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.thumb { width:100%; }
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-pad">
   <div class="col-8-12">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="column-content">
            <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
            <div class="meta-info-doub">
              <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
              <h3 class="title-double">Post2</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4-12">
    <div class="content">
     
    <div class="column-small-1">
      <div class="column-content">
        <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image thumb">
        <div class="meta-info-norm">
          <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
          <div class="info-title">
            <h3 class="title-normal">Post 3</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-small-2">
      <div class="column-content">
        <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image thumb">
        <div class="meta-info-norm">
          <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
          <div class="info-title">
            <h3 class="title-normal">Post1</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: The issue is i always wants them to align to the same height and then have the same padding. when i try yours in jsfiddle. it dont seem to align.  http://jsfiddle.net/nx0avzos/

Comment: Well in this case you need to provide original image with higher height. Can you try to experiment with an image of 740 x 366 px? It has to be some css you missed when recreating the layout from original website. So use your solution but with new image, and see if it works.

Comment: I've been experimenting for quite some time in the last couple of days and so far i've reached this point: http://jsfiddle.net/4a776hqk/ However the paddings are not the same which is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that you can adjust your layout by changing the bottom  padding in `.column-small-1` to 0 instead of 10px.

It may be possible to use margins instead of padding to adjust the two images on the right, and that could also fix the problem.

**Note:** The bottom edges are slightly off by 1px (in Firefox at least) and this artifact is also present in the original site that you posted as an example (the original site uses a WordPress theme).  This artifact is also present in my proposed solution.

```css
@import url('http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/simpleGrid.css');
 .column-big {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.column-small-1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.column-small-2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.column-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.column-content .meta-info-doub {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}
.column-content .meta-info-norm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.title-double {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  background: #161616;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title-normal {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  background: #161616;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5), -7px 0 0 rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.date-double {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}
.date-normal {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  display: block;
}
.column-content .content-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.column-content .content-image:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <div class="col-8-12">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="column-content">
        <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
        <div class="meta-info-doub">
          <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
          <h3 class="title-double">Post2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4-12">
    <div class="content">

      <div class="column-small-1">
        <div class="column-content">
          <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
          <div class="meta-info-norm">
            <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
            <div class="info-title">
              <h3 class="title-normal">Post 3</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column-small-2">
        <div class="column-content">
          <img src="http://motive.theme-sphere.com/news-demo/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/basketball_2-740x357.jpg" href="#" id="img-zoom" class="content-image">
          <div class="meta-info-norm">
            <h3 class="date-double">23. Oktober 2015</h3>
            <div class="info-title">
              <h3 class="title-normal">Post1</h3>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: But then again there wont be same padding around the different columns?

Comment: The images does not have to be correctly proportional just that they are aligned properly with the same margin/padding?

Comment: What is the reason for this 1px?

Comment: I am not quite sure where the 1px comes from.  I would need to look at the CSS more closely.